Error with React deployment on express server
I've created a simple react website and express server on which I want to deploy my website and make it accessible by the URL, I can see that scripts and css are loading in networks, also I can see the title and favicon of my website, but for some reason I cannot see the actual content. I already have this website uploaded to the different hosting and it is accessible here: https://agropv.kz/home, but how can I make it accessible on my own express server?  I

The first screenshot is what I receive in my browser,
second is how I contain my react build
the third one is what I've written in my server.ts

check the path of your file and you have to have one endpoint which means no /argo/* this must be the endpoint not file path
